# Split Nested JSON into Equal Sized Files PySpark/Python

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark that produces a nested json that looks like below :

```
{
    "batch_key": 1,
    "client_key": 1,
    "client_name": "ABC",
       "Claims": [
        {
            "claim_key": "A",
            "client_key": "B",
            "client_name": "ATT"
           
        },
        {
            "claim_key": "B",
            "client_key": "B",
            "client_name": "ATT"
           
        }
    ]
}
```

but Ideally it should be divided into equal parts, like below:

```
{
    "batch_key": 1,
    "client_key": 1,
    "client_name": "ABC",
       "Claims": [
        {
            "claim_key": "A",
            "client_key": "B",
            "client_name": "ATT"
           
        }
       
    ]
}


{
    "batch_key": 1,
    "client_key": 1,
    "client_name": "ABC",
       "Claims": [
        {
            "claim_key": "B",
            "client_key": "B",
            "client_name": "ATT"
           
        }
    ]
}
```

The actual json payload would be much bigger, hence the above split is needed so that API can consume it properly. Is there a way to achieve the above using sparksql/pyspark/python?

Comment: did this solution work?

Answer (score 0):

For each batch record you could extract the claims, `map` over the claims to create the multiple batches per claim and then call a flatten on the result to `flatten` the result.

For example assuming you have a stream/RDD of batches

```py
batches = batches
.map( lambda batch :   [{
    "batch_key": batch[ "batch_key"],
    "client_key": batch["client_key"],
    "client_name": batch["client_name"],
    "Claims": [ claim ]
} for claim in batch["Claims"] ] )
.flatten()
```

Based on your version of python and the number of attributes/keys you have in each JSON record you may consider different options to merge or create your new dictionary in the claims map - see [Merging dictionaries in Python 2 and 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python-taking-union-o/26853961#26853961)